# How can I split DAGs by categories, similar to Jenkins views?

Tags: airflow

We started moving from Jenkins to Airflow. The biggest problem that we're facing right now is that there are a lot of DAGs and it's difficult to navigate there.

Is there any way to split them by categories, similar to Jenkins views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tags, and filter by tags. Or you could name all the dags according to some prefixes (export, import, mnt, ml, whatever) and type in the search bar the prefix that you want to find the DAGs. Not exactly what you did before though.

Comment: Thanks Javier. That's in the right direction but not exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to see all the available tags, like we see the list of views in Jenkins?